# REST Strategy for protected images

Tags: javascript, python, node.js, rest, api

Currently, to get protected images we to need pass the access token and image url in the headers of a fetch request. It's problematic. First we have to get the blob, convert it to base64, and then append that to an image src.

The `<img src=''>` way is much simpler. I want to create an api on the server that will be as this: `/get-protected-images/?imageURL=demo-url-jpg&accessToken=ae3fo3`. So that we can do this on the front-end like this `<img src="/get-protected-images/?imageURL=demo-url-jpg&accessToken=ae3fo3" />`

The images are meant to be highly secure. What are the drawbacks of this method?

Comment: Do you have a login/user authentication?

Comment: no. Access is granted using accessTokens. Users login at the very first time, and then authenticate using accessTokens

Comment: Does the token change on every login?

Comment: The drawback is that your access token is then plainly visible in the DOM, so unless you invalidate that token frequently (at login or even more frequently) then you've only inconvenienced someone _a little bit_ in their pursuit of getting to your protected images.